# Error while counting characters in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, expr

I have a source code to find a number of words and characters in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
w=0
cc=0
for i in `cat $1`
do
j=$i
echo $j
w=$(($w+1))
c=`expr $j:'.*'`
cc=$(($cc+$c))
done
echo "no of characters"  $cc
echo "no of words" $w
```

But when I run it in the terminal the following error message is displayed^
./countWordChar 1.c
hello
./countWordChar: line 10: `0+hello:.*`: syntax error in expression (error token is `":.*"`)
no of characters 0
no of words 1

The 10th line in the code is `cc=$(($cc+$c))`. Apparently the c variable's value is not a number of characters of a word but the word itself.

And my 1.c file content is like that:

```
hello world
hello
```

What's wrong in the code?

PS. I know that there are builtin commands to count characters in a file but I must use the previous code according to my task.

Comment: The easy way : One simple command will print 1) number of lines 2) number of words 3) number of characters : $ `cat file | wc` ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expr` utility parses its arguments as an expression. The operators must appear as standalone arguments.

```
expr "$j" : '.*'
```

Above, `expr` is passed 4 arguments: `expr`, the content of `$j`, `:` and `.*`. Assuming the content of `$j` is not `(` or `!` (or things like `length` with some implementations), `expr` will under that as the `:` pattern matching operator applied to the content of `$j`.

To make it more robust, you'd want:

```
expr " $j" : '.*' - 1
```

(the second argument starting with a space cannot be recognised as an expr operator so that works around the problems noted above).

With

```
expr $j:'.*'
```

That would be two arguments (`expr` and the content of `$j` followed by `:.*` (assuming `$j` doesn't contain blank or wildcard characters, see below)). As `expr` only sees one argument (beside the command name), there's no operation requested, that's just one string argument which `expr` just echoes back.

Now, there are a number of other issues with your code:

Variable expansion and command substitution (`$((...))` or the deprecated `` `...` `` form you use), [when unquoted undergo `split+glob`](/q/171346). You do want the `split` part for the `` `cat $1` `` part (should have been `$(cat < "$1")`) to split it in words, but not the glob part, as otherwise that would expand `*` words for instance into the list of files in the current directory; and all the other variable expansions should be quoted (not necessary in assignments but quotes don't harm there).

Also, [you can't use `echo` for arbitrary data](/q/65803).

So it should be:

```
w=0 c=0
set -f #  disable glob
for i in $(cat < "$1"); do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
  w="$((w + 1))"
  c="$(expr " $i" : '.*' + "$c" - 1)"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `expr $j:'.*'` the command `expr` is receiving one (1) argument.
The command `expr` could not understand that.

The command `expr` needs each argument clearly separated:

```
expr "$j" ":" '.*'
```

That will be three (3) arguments given to the command `expr`. The quotes `"` around `:` are not really required. And is better to use an space before the string in `$j` to avoid some misinterpretations, as this:

```
expr " $j" : '.*'
```

That would make your script similar to this:

```
#!/bin/dash
w=0    cc=0
for i in `cat $1`; do
    echo "$j"
    w=$(($w+1))
    c=`expr " $i" : '.*'`
    cc=$((cc+c))
done
echo "no of characters"  $cc
echo "no of words" $w
```

---

But that is more of a dash script than a bash script (that's how you tagged your question).
A simplified bash script will look as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
w=0    cc=0
for i in $(< $1)
do
    ((w++))
    cc=((cc+${#i}))
done
echo "no of characters"  "$cc"
echo "no of words" "$w"
```

The `$(< $1)` is equivalent to `$(cat $1)` but slightly faster.
To increment w, is is shorter to use `w++`. And to count the number of characters we can use the length of `$i` as `${#i}`.

Or even shorter:

```
#!/bin/bash
w=0    cc=0
for i in $(< $1)
do  (( w++ , cc += ${#i} ))
done
printf "no of characters %s\nno of words %s\n"  "$cc" "$w"
```

By using bash (from 2.04-devel and up) comma `,` operator and using  `cc += ${#i}` as the equivalent of `cc = cc + ${#i}`.